# How often is jiffies updated?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I add few print statement in the start_kernel function in the Linux kernel to print out the jiffies value. The print statements were evenly spread out.

When the system booted up and checked out the printed values, they were all the same value (4294937296).

So, my question is how often is the value of jiffies updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is updated every `tick`

`tick` is triggered by timer/clock interrupt.

The interrupt is generated by Intel 8253 or HPET hardware

So it won't update until the hardware was property initialized.